# FullCalendar／Scrolling or event dragging animation is too slow in IE11 when many resources

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, internet-explorer-11, fullcalendar-4

I'm trying to make a calendar using FullCalendar(v4.4.0) Timeline View.
In IE11, when I add many resources(e.g. 100) to the calendar, scrolling or event dragging animation becomes slow.
When the number of resources is about 10, there is no problem for performance.
And when the browser is Chrome, it is also no problem.

Please tell me some adivces to improve this slow performance.

demo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/core@4.4.0/main.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/timeline@4.4.0/main.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/resource-timeline@4.4.0/main.min.css">
    <style>
        html, body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
        }
        #calendar {
            max-width: 900px;
            margin: 40px auto;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/core@4.4.0/main.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/interaction@4.4.0/main.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/timeline@4.4.0/main.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/resource-common@4.4.0/main.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/resource-timeline@4.4.0/main.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

            var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                plugins: [ 'interaction', 'resourceTimeline' ],
                timeZone: 'UTC',
                defaultView: 'resourceTimelineDay',
                aspectRatio: 1.5,
                header: {
                left: 'prev,next',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineWeek,resourceTimelineMonth'
                },
                editable: true,
                resourceLabelText: 'Rooms',
                resources: [
                    {
                        id: "a",
                        title: "1"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "b",
                        title: "2"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "c",
                        title: "3"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "d",
                        title: "4"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "e",
                        title: "5"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "f",
                        title: "6"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z7",
                        title: "7"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z8",
                        title: "8"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z9",
                        title: "9"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z10",
                        title: "10"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z11",
                        title: "11"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z12",
                        title: "12"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z13",
                        title: "13"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z14",
                        title: "14"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z15",
                        title: "15"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z16",
                        title: "16"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z17",
                        title: "17"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z18",
                        title: "18"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z19",
                        title: "19"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z20",
                        title: "20"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z21",
                        title: "21"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z22",
                        title: "22"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z23",
                        title: "23"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z24",
                        title: "24"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z25",
                        title: "25"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z26",
                        title: "26"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z27",
                        title: "27"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z28",
                        title: "28"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z29",
                        title: "29"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z30",
                        title: "30"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z31",
                        title: "31"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z32",
                        title: "32"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z33",
                        title: "33"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z34",
                        title: "34"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z35",
                        title: "35"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z36",
                        title: "36"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z37",
                        title: "37"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z38",
                        title: "38"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z39",
                        title: "39"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z40",
                        title: "40"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z41",
                        title: "41"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z42",
                        title: "42"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z43",
                        title: "43"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z44",
                        title: "44"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z45",
                        title: "45"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z46",
                        title: "46"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z47",
                        title: "47"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z48",
                        title: "48"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z49",
                        title: "49"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z50",
                        title: "50"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z51",
                        title: "51"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z52",
                        title: "52"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z53",
                        title: "53"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z54",
                        title: "54"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z55",
                        title: "55"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z56",
                        title: "56"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z57",
                        title: "57"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z58",
                        title: "58"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z59",
                        title: "59"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z60",
                        title: "60"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z61",
                        title: "61"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z62",
                        title: "62"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z63",
                        title: "63"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z64",
                        title: "64"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z65",
                        title: "65"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z66",
                        title: "66"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z67",
                        title: "67"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z68",
                        title: "68"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z69",
                        title: "69"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z70",
                        title: "70"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z71",
                        title: "71"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z72",
                        title: "72"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z73",
                        title: "73"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z74",
                        title: "74"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z75",
                        title: "75"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z76",
                        title: "76"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z77",
                        title: "77"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z78",
                        title: "78"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z79",
                        title: "79"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z80",
                        title: "80"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z81",
                        title: "81"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z82",
                        title: "82"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z83",
                        title: "83"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z84",
                        title: "84"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z85",
                        title: "85"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z86",
                        title: "86"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z87",
                        title: "87"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z88",
                        title: "88"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z89",
                        title: "89"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z90",
                        title: "90"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z91",
                        title: "91"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z92",
                        title: "92"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z93",
                        title: "93"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z94",
                        title: "94"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z95",
                        title: "95"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z96",
                        title: "96"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z97",
                        title: "97"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z98",
                        title: "98"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z99",
                        title: "99"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "z100",
                        title: "100"
                    }
                ],
                events: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-events.json?single-day&for-resource-timeline'
            });
            calendar.render();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: IE's Javascript engine and rendering engine is slow. It's old technology. Edge has replaced it. There's not much you can do. Although I would point out at 100 is a **large** number of resources. Do your users really want to see all that information on the screen at the same time? It's too much to take in, and hard to find things. For the sake of your general user experience, I would suggest you consider some kind of system where users can filter the list of resources by some kind of group or other properties.

Comment: Try to clear the browser data or restart the IE browser, I have tested your code on my side, it seems OK, not very slow in IE browser. Besides, I think you could try to add part of resources when page Initialization, then when scroll the calendar, you could use the AddResource method to add the resource dynamically.

Comment: @ADyson Certainly, what you say is understandable. I will rethink specifications. Thank you!

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT In my environment, it is still slow. About Using of "addResource", I think it is applicable to my program. I will consider your advice. Thank you!